# How to run code when system boots up in a Windows service application?

Tags: c++, winapi, service, boot

I have a local system service application, written with C++/MFC, designed to run on Windows OS. I need to run the code inside this service when the system just boots up. My initial idea was to run it from the beginning of the ServiceMain() stand-in function, that is defined by a call to StartServiceCtrlDispatcher() API, but the issue is that it is also run if I stop and then restart this service.

Comment: Sounds more like you want a driver than a service...

Comment: No, all I need to know is the time when the system booted up.

Comment: If that's the case, what's wrong with `net statistics server`?

Comment: If you just want to know the uptime, why don't you ask: how can I determine the system uptime?

Comment: @jamesdlin: I asked it this way because it would be nice to know how to do it in your own C++ code and not depend on some outside service.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you don't need a service. You can do the same with scheduled task. You can use `taskschd.msc` to create a task with trigger to launch a task on system startup, or from command line:

```
schtasks.exe /Create /SC ONSTART /TN MyTaskName /TR c:\Path_to_my_tool\my_executable.exe
```

Comment: Thanks. You see, I'm not creating a service just for this purpose. I already have a service where I need to know the system boot time. Scheduled task manager is a service itself, so it must know somehow, right?

Comment: If you already have an exe that is a service, call it as a scheduled task, with a special parameter. E.g.: `myservice.exe /OnStartup`. In the existing service parse command line and execute the code you want to run on startup only if command line option is present.